# Datepicker was not hiding while pressing back or forward browser button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

hi currently 'm working in jQuery Mobile site.i was displayed a date picker on a text box click .While date-picker was displayed then i click back or forward button in the browser then the date-picker (calendar) was not hide it still displaying on other windows. Please help me to slow this issue

date-picker On a text box click date-picker:

[image]

If we click back button while above date picker was  in display state then the date-picker displayed in other page also the image is below

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: back forward button suppose to change the month. So it won't hide the widget. If you want a custom function then you gonna have to hack the plugin and write your own code for the back button. Else you can provide another back forward buttons in your system other than the default back forward button which is used to change month

Comment: @MayuMayooresan thanks for your reply. I was not mention the calendar back forward button, i am getting this while clicking browser's back & forward button

Comment: @MayuMayooresan suggest me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is not optimized for jQuery Mobile. If you want a date picker I would suggest you use [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/).

[DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) is highly customisable and being used in enterprise solutions. Above all its an open source solution.

Comment: it working good but some time the calendar was not displayed on the icon click. I have to click and hold the cursor on that position then only calendar displayin gin some time

Comment: how to control the click area to display the calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can Add Below Code in MasterPage. It'll work

$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {

```
if (data.state.direction == "back") {
    // Make use of the directional information  
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();

}
```

});